# Is "give me a five" the same as "give me five" or incorrect?

Tags: differences

I mean the physical gesture of slapping hands together. Any difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some examples of sentences here.

Comment: give me a five does not mean: physical gesture of slapping someone's hand in the air with  yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Give me five* means slapping palms above each other's heads as a a greeting, celebration gesture, or sign of joy. Sometimes one can also say [**Give me a five**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=give+me+a+five), *Give me (some) skin!*, *Skin me!*, *Slip me five!*, *Slip me some skin!*, and *High five!* with the same meaning.

> [**Give me five!**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Give+me+five!): *Sl.* Slap my hand! (as a greeting or to show joy)

Comment: So, both 'give me a five' and 'give me five' are OK? But @thirdnews said it's incorrect.

Comment: @Anderson It all depends on what you mean by "Give me five" in your question. Are you talking about money or the physical gesture of slapping hands together as a greeting or to show joy? You should add more context to your question. :-)

Comment: @Anderson http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fZD9zNipOVA

Comment: @Anderson The thing is "Give me five" can also mean "Give me five of something." E.g. "How many apples do you want?" -- "Give me five.", or "How much [money] do you need?" -- "Give me five (dollars)." But, "I need to break a ten-dollar bill. Can you give me 'a' five and five ones [=a five-dollar bill and five one-dollar bills]."

Comment: In practice, the ambiguity isn't a meaningful concern. There is almost no context in which the two could be confused, particularly since you'll almost always have your hand up when asking someone to 'give you five'. They'll both probably be understood, but 'give me five' is much more natural.

Comment: No native speaker would confuse |Give me five.| with |Give me a five.|

Answer (score 3):

The word 'five' in the "give me five" expression refers to your hand's 5 digits -so saying 'give me a five' digits is incorrect.  BTW, “give me **a** five” generally refers to a five dollar bill.

Answer (score 0):

"Give Me Five" is not referring to High Fives.
to give five is a reciprocating action where on person horizontally holds out their hand (palms up) to receive another persons friendly hand slap then returning "five" back to their friend. Again... THIS IS A TWO PART ACTION.

Comment: This is not correct. ‘Give me five’ at least as frequently, if not more so, refers to high fives.